# Laggy when switching tabBarController to a tableView with many cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

My app is based on a tabBarController and has 2 tabs.

I load data for the 2nd tab in the background while the app launches at tab 1, so users don't need to wait when they click tab 2.

My problem is: it's laggy to switch to tab 2 if I load the data in advance and there is much data to show in cells of the tableView belonging to tab 2. If there are not many cells to show, then it's not laggy at all.

I guess it's because generating cells is time-consuming, so the view is blocked when there are too many cells. How do I optimize this?

Comment: can you please attach your code so we can help :D

Comment: generating cells time is not  a big deal , if u using uitableviewcell dequeue

Comment: Oh, yeah, the height of my cell is calculated dynamically based on the content size of the data, I guess the thing that is really time-consuming is calculating the height.
anyways, I believe this is a general problem when there are really many cells, so I am not sure which part of my code you want to see.
Like how do i load the data in background, my tableview datasource, or anything else?

Comment: then you do not need to calculate the height of all cells at once, do it for the cells fitting the first two screens (you can always check the totalHeight with the screenRect while looping) and then update the cells heights container somehow later.

Comment: @teamnorge, your suggestion makes sense! Can you answer the question and show me the detail? Thanks :D

Comment: @Brian, the example could be rather advanced, so the quick questions, what's inside the particular cell, is it's just text which you can place inside `UILabel` or `UITextView` or is this something more advanced. Also, are you considering having cells of the different height depending on the content to be placed inside. Also, are you going to support orientations, so the height of the same cell changes while rotating. And finally what's your data container, is it's just Array of Strings/Dictionaries or core data?

Comment: The cells are made up of multiple `UILabel`s, but only 1 label has dynamical height. The height of this label is calculated by the content size of related data. I don't need to support orientations and use Array to store the data. I think you don't need to tell me the every detail, just tell me the key concepts. (conforming some protocols to do something, for instance), so the answer will be more general and be helpful to more people :)

Comment: @Brian using auto layout you can easily  create  a dynamic cell http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 0):

**Important!** This code has not been tested in the XCode, but contains some parts from real projects.

The `CellView` class could be created either as a Nib or even manually using `calculateCellHeight` method from `ServicesHelper.m`. In both cases the `layoutSubviews` method must be implemented where the resize `detailTextLabel` `UILabel` code to be placed. The `CellView` labels Font and Color must be the same as used in `calculateCellHeight` method.

**ServicesHelper.m**

```
#define FontRegular(fontSize) [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:fontSize]

// the height of fixed part of the cell, fixed height UILabel + some padding
#define kFixedPartCellHeight 20
#define kLeftPaddingWidth 20

#define kLandscapeHeightKey @"landscapeKey"
#define kPortraitHeight @"portraitKey"

+ (NSDictionary *) calculateCellHeight: (NSString *) text {

// dynamic height label
UILabel *detailTextLabel = [UILabel new];

UIFont *mainFont = FontRegular(14.0);

// specifying font and colour to be used inside cell is important to get precise frame rect
[detailTextLabel setFont: mainFont];
[detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

[textLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

// get the width of the cell for both orientations
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

CGFloat landscapeWidth = MAX (screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
CGFloat portraitWidth = MIN (screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);

// kLeftPaddingWidth - is just a white space left and right to the UILabel inside cell
// we set the UILabel width with maximum possible height, then set text and shrink it using sizeToFit to get the exact size

detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0 , landscapeWidth - kLeftPaddingWidth * 2, CGFLOAT_MAX);
textLabel.frame = detailTextLabel.frame;

detailTextLabel.text = text;
[detailTextLabel sizeToFit];

CGFloat landscapeHeight = detailTextLabel.frame.size.height + kFixedPartCellHeight;

detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0 , portraitWidth - kLeftPaddingWidth * 2, CGFLOAT_MAX);
textLabel.frame = detailTextLabel.frame;

detailTextLabel.text = text;
[detailTextLabel sizeToFit];

CGFloat portraitHeight = detailTextLabel.frame.size.height + kFixedPartCellHeight;

return  @{kLandscapeHeightKey: landscapeHeight, kPortraitHeightKey: portraitHeight};
}
```

**TableView.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfTexts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dictOfHeights;
```

**TableView.m**

```
- (void) precalculateHeight {
    if (nil == self.dictOfHeights) self.dictOfHeights = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    // height of two screens
    CGFloat maxHeight = MAX (screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height) * 2;
    CGFloat totalHeight = 0;
    CGFloat portraitHeight;
    CGFloat landscapeHeight;
    NSDictionary *dictHeights;

    for (int i = 0; i < self.arrayOfTexts.count; i++ ) {

      dictHeights = [ServicesHelper calculateCellHeight: arrayOfTexts[i]];
      portraitHeight = [dictHeights[kPortraitHeightKey] floatValue];
      [self.dictOfHeights setValue: dictHeights forKey:@(i)];
      totalHeight += portraitHeight;
      if (totalHeight > maxHeight) break;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (self.dictOfHeights && self.dictOfHeights[@(indexPath.row)]) {
      return UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ? 
             [self.dictOfHeights[@(indexPath.row)][kPortraitHeightKey] floatValue] : 
             [self.dictOfHeights[@(indexPath.row)][kLandscapeHeightKey] floatValue];
  } else {
    // you decide, call calculateCellHeight for particular row, right from here, or also calculate rows height for the coming set of cells
    // @todo:
  }
  return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```